# Why is Excel saying that my ActiveX object is not on the Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, barcode-printing, datamatrix, barcodetype-39

I'm trying to use BarcodeTools' data matrix ActiveX object to be able to create a data matrix code on my excel sheet. I want the data to be encoded in the barcode to be through my user messages probing for the data. This is because I'm lookin to have it printed for it to be scanned later. For whatever reason though I just can't get excel to verify that I have the ActiveX object on my worksheet.

I'm able to place it in the worksheet. But when I step through the code it seems that the checks I have in place display there is nothing there.

I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing from using this ActiveX tool. Especially since when the macro runs, I am still getting a barcode to print. But it's not encoded with the string that the user would create. I know that Barcode Tools has their barcodes set as added ActiveX objects. An I can see when I right click on the barcode its properties. I'm just not sure why the barcode isn't taking the code when I have its setting for linked cell A1, nothing happens. With nothing changing when I try to change both that property and the data encoded property.

```
Public Sub CreateAndPrintLabel()
    Dim createLabel As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim labelInfo As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As Object

    ' Step 1: Ask the user if they wish to create a label
    createLabel = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a label?", vbYesNo)

    If createLabel = vbYes Then
       ' Step 2: Prompt for each parameter
        licensePlate = InputBox("Enter License Plate:")
        partNumber = InputBox("Enter Part Number:")
        Description = InputBox("Enter Description:")
        ExpirationDate = InputBox("Enter Expiration Date:")

        ' Step 3: Validate and display entered information
        labelInfo = licensePlate & " | " & partNumber & " | " & Description & " | " & ExpirationDate
        confirmMsg = "Is the following information correct?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & labelInfo
        confirmed = MsgBox(confirmMsg, vbYesNo) = vbYes

        ' Step 4: Allow correction or confirmation
        If Not confirmed Then
            ' Provide an option to go through the steps again if the information was incorrect
            Call CreateAndPrintLabel
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Store labelInfo in cell A1 on Sheet1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = labelInfo
        
        ' Check if Data Matrix data matches the content in cell A1
        Dim dataMatrixControl1 As OLEObject
        On Error Resume Next
        Set dataMatrixControl1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("DataMatrixCtrl.1")
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not dataMatrixControl1 Is Nothing Then
            If dataMatrixControl1.Object.DataToEncode = labelInfo Then
                ' Step 5: Print the label using Brother printer
                Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
                sPath = "C:\Users\giovanni.fontanetta\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
                
                
                ' Open lbx file
                If ObjDoc.Open(sPath) Then
                    ' Set text for the entire label
                    ObjDoc.SetText 0, dataMatrixContent

                    ' Print the label
                    ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault
                    ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
                    ObjDoc.EndPrint

                    ' Close lbx file
                    ObjDoc.Close
                Else
                    MsgBox "Failed to open label file."
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Data Matrix content does not match A1."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "ActiveX Data Matrix control not found on the sheet."
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Print_Label()
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As bpac.Document
    Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
    sPath = "C:\Users\giovanni.fontanetta\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
    
    'Open lbx file
    bRet = ObjDoc.Open(sPath)
    If (bRet <> False) Then

        ' Start Print-Setting
        ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault
        
        ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault

        ' Finish Print-Setting.iStart the printing.j
        ObjDoc.EndPrint
        
        ' Close lbx file
        ObjDoc.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you "place it in the worksheet"? Then, do you see its name after that?

Comment: I will go to Developer tab > insert > More tools in the activeX options > then select DataMatrix Ctrl Class. Once this is finished I can draw on the keyboard

Comment: Does this give you any useful clues? `Dim obj As Object: For Each obj In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects: Debug.Print obj.Name:Next`

Comment: No. When I step through no changes or differences occur

Comment: When you run the code I posted take a look in the Immediate pane (Ctrl+G to show if not already open) in the VB editor  - what do you see there?

Comment: I see that it states DataMatrixCtrl1. But nothing else

Comment: Not `DataMatrixCtrl.1` ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Comment: Unfortunately while I haven't gotten the ActiveX object to work on the workbook, I have at least managed to have the workbook send and print a data matrix barcode to my brother printer. By using some of the objects noted in Brothers manual, I've been able to have the string be the data that is enocded.

Comment: While I would like to have used the ActiveX object, it will have to do for now with my current project. A strong thank you to Tim for willing to assist! ♡

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("DataMatrixCtrl1")`  should work then.